# How do I gain access to the documents folder (UWP)

Tags: c#, file, uwp, directory, document

When closing the UWP I will get a list of items from a database. I want to save this list in a file which will be created/edited in the documents folder.

I tried to gain access to the Documents folder by this:

`StorageFolder stFo = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;`

My Problem is that I have no access to the Documents Folder ('An exception of type "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" occured...').

Now I have read that you could get access by adding some lines to `Package.appxmanifest`

```
<Package xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities">
```

and

```
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="appCaptureSettings"/>
    <uap Name="documentsLibrary"/>
  </Capabilities>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Is there another way to gain access? (If yes, an example for it would be awesome)

*edit*

This is probably important: This UWP is sideloaded

Comment: Have you read [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#create-and-read-a-local-file)?

Comment: Another words: why do you think that you need to save them in `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`?

Comment: @vasily.sib I'll read trough it. - I don't neccessarily need to save it it the documents folder but I want to know how to save it there now.

Comment: You should have some more information on the exception. For instance, when I run your sample I get this - `Access to the specified location (DocumentsLibrary) requires a file type association to be declared in the application manifest.` A quick Google search should tell you how to add your specified file type.

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough to add the declare the `documentsLibrary` capability. You also need to add file type associations to your app manifest to declare what specific file types your app can access: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7ee61fd7-db6d-49a6-bda4-701105a500e7/uwpcant-access-documents-library-in-universal-windows-app?forum=wpdevelop

Note that the Documents library is not intended for general use though.

You should consider using `ApplicationData.LocalFolder` or `LocalCacheFolder`, `RoamingFolder`, `SharedLocalFolder`, or `TemporaryFolder` based on how your data should be stored.

Comment: We are using ApplicationData folder, but when the user re-installs the app all these folders get wiped out, so we are looking for a best practice to preserve the status of the app across installations. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Use the Credential manager. However, the data will be roamed between devices and can't be stopped.