# How can I get a consistent path for read/write application in C# apps?

Tags: c#, windows-10, environment-variables, directory-structure

I have a C# app that needs to be able to **read and write** files that will be available to **all users**.

I thought that this would give me an appropriate location to store these files:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

I have 2 apps that need to access the same folders. The main app is UWP and there is a utility app which is a console app. Running on Windows 10.

The main app returns this:

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\ba131026-0d4a-4706-afec-3246196e7d60

The console app returns the much simpler:

> C:\ProgramData

I don't mind which I use, but I just need them to be able to both access the same folder. Is there some method to always get the same folder from both types of app?

Comment: Just tried out Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments instead, and it consistently returns C:\Users\Public\Documents, so that might be a better option?

Answer (score 2):

UWP apps run in a sandbox, that's why `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` doesn't point to the "regular" folder `C:\ProgramData`

I would advise against using `CommonDocuments` since that means giving the UWP app more permissions than needed, and it seems rather cumbersome (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289334/how-do-i-gain-access-to-the-documents-folder-uwp)).

Instead, I would recommend accessing the UWP app's folder from within the console app, which always will be `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Packages/AUMID`, where AUMID is the UWP app identifier (Application User Model ID).

```
var aumid = "ba131026-0d4a-4706-afec-3246196e7d60"
var path = Path.Combine(
     Environment.GetFolderPath(
         Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), 
         $"/Packages/{aumid}"
     )
);
```